# How can I develop a sharepoint 2007 widget to generate permission of documents report on sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, permissions

I want to develop a report which can show all permission of documents under a specific folder on sharepoint 2007.
How can I do this ? Can someone point me the right direction ?

Comment: Is this for a folder under a document library?  Are permissions being inherited down?

Comment: yes, should be document library, and permissions is not inherited down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about looking at these codeplex projects and adapting to your needs

[Codeplex - Sharepoint Access Checker Web Part](http://accesschecker.codeplex.com/)

[Codeplex - Sharepoint Permissions Manager](http://permissionsmanager.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at some no-code solutions using web services and dataview web parts. I've not done it down to the item level, but you might be able to take the information here: http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=676af157%2D7d96%2D4e15%2Da987%2D54b8a3e4d948&ID=40&RootFolder=%2A and adapt it to work for you as well.

Comment: How can I export them into a excel ? any suggest ?